# Как дождаться нажатия на кнопку в Swing?

Tags: java, swing, gui

У меня в классе `RegistrationFrame`, который реализует интерфейс `ActionListener`, по нажатию на кнопку создается класс `Person`. В отдельном классе, `Test`, в отдельном потоке событий, я вызываю конструктор `RegistrationFrame`, после чего хочу выдернуть из экземпляра класса `RegistrationFrame` поле с классом `Person`, следующим образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RegistrationFrame registrationFrame = new RegistrationFrame();
                System.out.println(registrationFrame.getPerson().toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Очевидно, возникает `NullPointerException`, потому что программа не ждет нажатия кнопки(по которой создается экземпляр Person), и сразу же после вызова конструктора дергает еще не проинициализированного `person`. Как заставить программу ждать нажатия на кнопку? Весь `jFrame` у меня создается внутри конструктора `RegistrationFrame`, если нужно, могу добавить код.

Comment: А как Вы обратились к `registrationFrame` если он определен в анонимном `Runnable`?

Comment: Проверил, если запускать конструктор из основного потока, а не из анонимного `Runnable`, ситуация та же.

Comment: Я это к тому что у Вас `registrationFrame` где-то еще определен. Лучше прояснить где и как Вы к нему будете обращаться.

Comment: Вы правы, исправил ошибку, на которую Вы указали, тот же `NullPointerException`. То есть суть вопроса остается прежней=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить наоборот: создать слушателя, который будет вызываться при каждом создании `Person` и с его помощью подписаться на создание объектов из внешнего класса.

Примитивный пример (код не компилировал):

1. Создаем интерфейс-слушатель

   ```
   interface PersonListener {
       void personCreated(Person person);
   }
   ```
2. Добавляем в `RegistrationFrame` метод добавления слушателя и вызов слушателей при создании `Person`

   ```
   class RegistrationFrame ... {
       private final List<PersonListener> personListeners = new ArrayList<PersonListener>();

       public void addPersonListener(PersonListener listener) {
           personListeners.add(listener);
       }

       private void notifyPersonListeners(Person person) {
           for(PersonListener listener: personListeners) {
               listener.personCreated(person);
           }
       }

           //... где-то в обработчике кнопки, в котором создается Person
           Person person = new Person();
           ...
           notifyPersonListeners(person);
   }
   ```
3. В основном потоке слушаем создание `Person`

   ```
   RegistrationFrame registrationFrame = new RegistrationFrame();
   registrationFrame.addPersonListener(new PersonListener() {
       @Override
       void personCreated(Person person) {
           System.out.println(person.toString());
       }
   }
   ```

Так код по обработке новых объектов будет вызываться только при их создании. В реализацию `PersonListener` можно вшить вызов другого потока, если требуется.